# Visio - Convert ".svg" to ".emf" format

Tags: svg, converters, visio

My goal is to convert pictures from `.svg` format into `.emf`, remaining the size, resolution, etc!!

The best solution that I found was using Visio, because of the quality after conversion and also if I need to resize the pictures, they don’t lose quality.

Please check the picture that I am sending on the link.

This picture shows the appearance when I open a `.svg` file in Visio 2010. As you can see, the image is very clear and the limits well defined!

(picture. 1)

I have already fit the drawing to the page using [this tip](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980530/en-us)

(picture. 2)

To get the `emf` format I save this file as `.emf` format:

(picture. 3)

The quality is good when it is opened with Microsoft Picture Manager, but the problem is detectable when this picture is inserted on the software that I want to use. The `.emf` file looks well, but when I convert from `svg` to `.emf`, Visio inserts an invisible frame around the image, if I open this `emf` file with paint it looks like it is inserted 1 pixel size for all borders!

(picture. 4)

As you can see here, the size image from Visio should looks like this (Inkscape) but it’s inserted a frame like this:

(picture. 5)
(picture. 6)

Does anybody know how to get a solution to this, using either Visio or other software?

<s>Please do the [download of the files.](https://www.sendspace.com/file/sn153g)</s>
 *(Link is no longer valid.)*

I appreciate all feedback.

Comment: Late comment: [svg2emf](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/svg2emf) is a free Java tool to accomplish the conversion. Be warned: it needs quite a few prerequisite libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for preparing so much for this question and providing the ZIP. It was a very thorough job.

I don't have definitive knowledge here but my experience is this is very common EMF which - as I understand it always require a bounding box to be stored in the file.

The only option I can think of is using another format for example EPS - but it depends on what the final program you are using supports. Exporting to a bitmap format works better for some applications - though it may not be desirable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use inkscape to convert from svg to emf.

In the Inkscape GUI: Menu File -> Save As -> Select emf as Target

Or in the command line mode: `inkscape -z src.svg -M target.emf`

Comment: I can't see the images, so I can't verify if inkscape can solve the problem.